# Using invisible UILabel and trigger UITextView events or not using the UILabel and handle UITextView tap recognizers

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

A) First I'll expose the way I'm trying to solve this WITHOUT using the invisible UILabel

1) The first tap over the UITextView makes it the First Responder. This would be the default behavior (it is no needed to add code for this) but since the tap recognizer should trigger other actions later, it is also needed to create the personalized tap recognizer:

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapRecognized:)];
  [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [TextView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
  [TextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [singleTap release];

-(IBAction)singleTapRecognized:(id)sender
    {
      [TextView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

2) When the text is changed a menu bar should be hidden. This doesn't create any issue because its only needed to add code inside the TextViewDidChange:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
  if (bTitleBar)
  {
    bTitleBar = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30f];
    menuBar.transform =
    CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                                     menuBar.frame.origin.x,
                                     -50 
                                     );

    CGRect newFrameSize;
    currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (currentOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||currentOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
      newFrameSize = CGRectMake(96, 0, txtMain.frame.size.width, 605);
    }
    else
    {
      newFrameSize = CGRectMake(96, 0, txtMain.frame.size.width, 270);
    }
    textView.frame = newFrameSize;
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
  }
}
```

3) Next tap over the UITextView (after the text has changed and the MenuBar is hidden) should trigger visibility to the menu bar again. In that case I would add code inside singleTapRecognized so it would be shown again, but for some reason the UITapGestureRecognizer singleTap stops working and consequently  the singleTapRecognized method is not triggered any more. So I started with the B Plan:

B) The solution I tried was to use an invisible UILabel that I attached visually (not programmatically) over the UITextView. I also made its corresponding IBOutlet and set up the reference. Now the UIGestureRecognizer singleTap is added to the UILabel and not to the UITextView. 
The problem is that the UITextView can't be scrolled or tapped because the UILabel is OVER it and becomes an obstacle.

Any ideas of how to solve this? Which is better to continue working with, A or B plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would go to plan C. If you log the text view's gestureRecognizers property, you will see that there are a bunch of them, so messing with them seems fraught with difficulty. Normally, the second tap on the text view changes the selection (or brings up the replacement text popover) and calls the textViewDidChangeSelection: method -- I would use that method, and check to see if the menu bar is hidden or not -- if it is, bring it back and then call super textViewDidChangeSelection: to allow the text view to do its thing.